# Export an excel sheet in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I am trying to upload an excel sheet with Codeigniter 3, My SQL, and PHP 8.2.

Kindly help me with the library and its usage on this task.

Comment: Consider including the code applicable to your prior attempt to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export your results, the easiest way is to use the csv method.

```html
$filename="index_res.php";
header("Content-Description:File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type:application/csv");
ob_clean();
$file=fopen("php://output","w");
//mysql result goes here
foreach($your_data as $data)
{
fputcsv($file,$data);
}
fclose($file);
exit;
```